# End of line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, eol

I have problem - can't detect what eol char used on the page.

For example server send this data:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
echo "1\r2";
```

Now i try detect eol (\r == 13):

```
document.body.textContent.charCodeAt(1);
```

But JS return 10 instead 13. If try use other special char then JS return correct char code.

How i can get original page data without any changes if i can't detect eol on server, script out the stream and i can't use XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: *"...if i can't change anything on server "* You mean you can't change the PHP code you've quoted?

Comment: Wait...you're returning plaintext and say you can't use `XMLHttpRequest`, so how would you run JavaScript to operate on that response? An `iframe`?

Comment: Yes, i can't change php script.

Comment: It's very simple sample - we can use console for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't change the PHP and you **have** to rely on getting the text back from `document.body.textContent`, you can't rely on line endings not being modified. Browsers render content normalizing whitespace; by the time you access `document.body.textContent`, that text isn't the literal text your server sent back, it's been manipulated to form a DOM document, and then your accessing `textContent` gets the string version of that DOM document. Line endings may well have been normalized and almost certainly **will** be.

You'll *have* to change something on the server or use `XMLHttpRequest`, or you can't do it.

---

From your comment:

> Ok - i can change php script but can't detect eol on server.

Well, that's different then:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode("1\r2");
?>
```

and

```
JSON.parse(document.body.textContent).charCodeAt(1) // 13
```

Comment: Can i get source data with some other methods?

Comment: @eolusr: Nothing other than XHR comes to mind, no. XHR would work.

Comment: Ok - i can change php script but can't detect eol on server. It's help?

Comment: :) I mean that I can not influence the output - i out the stream.

Comment: @eolusr: You said you can change the script. Can you or can't you?

Comment: I can change script, but i can't detect eol with data or change data (like json_encode or other encoding).

Comment: @eolusr: That makes no sense. I'm afraid I'm going to have to give up now.

Comment: Maybe something can disable normalization with DOMConfiguration? http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#DOMConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Even if you send the text as `text/plain`, most browsers will still render a HTML document. Otherwise, you couldn't do `document.body`, because there wouldn't be any `body`.

And then, from [§8.2.2.5 Preprocessing the input stream](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#preprocessing-the-input-stream),

> "CR" (U+000D) characters and "LF" (U+000A) characters are treated
>   specially. All CR characters must be converted to LF characters, and
>   any LF characters that immediately follow a CR character must be
>   ignored. Thus, newlines in HTML DOMs are represented by LF characters,
>   and there are never any CR characters in the input to the [tokenization](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tokenization)
>   stage.

So it's not possible.

Comment: Except that plain text isn't HTML.

Comment: Can i disable normalizing/render and get data any other method?

Comment: @eolusr With XMLHttpRequest there wouldn't be any preprocessing so it would work.